# STM32L0xx MCU: J-Link EraseChip Issues via Jlink_X64.dll

Tags: python, dll, stm32, segger-jlink

I need help with erasing an **STM32L083** using a J-Link. I have the Jlink_X64.dll library and I am calling its functions from Python. However, when I call **JLINK_EraseChip()**, it returns a *pylink.errors.JLinkEraseException: Failed to erase sector error* and the MCU does not get erased. Interestingly, erasing another MCU like STM32L152 works fine. Also, if I use J-Flash Lite to erase the chip, it is successful. After erasing the MCU with J-Flash Lite, if I try erasing it again using JLINK_EraseChip(), it works. Do you have any suggestions on what else I could try? BTW, the processor is not locked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution: writing 0x015500AA on address 0x1FF80000 causes mass erase of the MCU